# How to deploy a django/gunicorn application as a systemd service?

Tags: django, service, environment-variables, virtualenv, systemd

### Context

For the last few years, I have been only using **docker** to containerize and distribute django applications. For the first time, I am asked to set things so it could be deployed **the old way**. I am looking for a way to *nearly* achieve the levels of **encapsulation** and **automation** I am used to while avoiding any pitfalls

### Current heuristic

So, the application (**my_app**):

- is build as a `.whl`
- comes with [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/)
- is published on a private Nexus and
- can be installed on any of the client's server with a simple `pip install`

(it relies on Apache as reverse proxy / static files server and Postgresql but this is irrelevant for this discussion)

To make sure that the app will remain available, I thought about running it as a **service** managed by **systemd**. Based on [this article](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6), here is what `/etc/systemd/system/my_app.service` could look like

```
[Unit]
Description=My app service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=centos
ExecStart=gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application --bind 8000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and, from what I understand, I could provide this service with **environment variables** to be read by `os.environ.get()` somewhere in `/etc/systemd/system/my_app.service.d/.env`

```
SECRET_KEY=somthing
SQL_ENGINE=somthing
SQL_DATABASE=somthing
SQL_USER=somthing
SQL_PASSWORD=somthing
SQL_HOST=somthing
SQL_PORT=somthing
DATABASE=somthing
```

### Opened questions

1. First if all, are there any obvious pitfalls?
2. **upgrade**. Will restarting the service be enough to upgrade the application after a `pip install --upgrade my_app`?
3. **library conflicts** Is it possible to make sure that `gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application` will use the correct versions of libraries used by the project? Or do I need to use a **virtualenv**? If so, should `source /path/to/the/venv/bin/activate` be used in `ExecStart` or is there a cleaner way to make sure `ExecStart` runs in a separate virtual environment?
4. where should `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py collectstatic` live? Should I use those in /etc/systemd/system/my_app.service

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try, but I'm also not sure if it works. This is for the third question.

You have to create a `virtualenv`, install `gunicorn` and `django` in it.

1. Create a file python like this "gunicorn_config.py"
2. Fill like this, or can be adjusted as needed:

```
#gunicorn_config.py

command = 'env/bin/gunicorn'

pythonpath = 'env/myproject'

bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
```

3. in the `systemd ExecStart` fill `env/bin/gunicorn -c env/gunicorn_config.py myproject.wsgi`.